# 同じ番号を含むものの中から番号ごとに数を数える

Tags: python, python3, bioinformatics

CHRの中は`1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ・・・・22 22 X X ・・Y Y    ・・MT MT MT`という感じになっています。この中から、番号ごとにその数をカウントしたいです。数字だけでなく、文字もあるので、どうすれば良いかわかりません。

```
import sys
import os

with open('test.vcf','r') as file:
    lines = file.read().split('\n')

    for line in lines:
        a = line.split('\t')
        CHR = a[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

collections.Counterをお使いください。

[collections --- コンテナデータ型 — Python 3.7.3 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

これは、要素のキー毎に出現回数をカウントする `dict` のサブクラスで、まさにそのような用途のために存在するクラスです。

以下のようなコードで動作を確認できるかと存じます。

```py
import sys
import os
from collections import Counter

chars = []
with open('test.vcf','r') as file:
    lines = file.read().split('\n')

    for line in lines:
        a = line.split('\t')
        CHR = a[0]
        chars.append(CHR)

c = Counter(chars)
print(c)
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。a[0]をどうやってリストに変換すればいいかわからなかったので役に立ちました。

Comment: この回答でよろしければ、承認（✓マーク）をお願いします。[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか? - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)