# #(コメントアウト)を削除したい

Tags: python, python3, bioinformatics

vcfファイルには最初の何行にも渡って#で書かれた箇所があり、読み込んだ時に#も一緒に出力してしまいます。その結果、counterでは`{('3':987, '7':654, ・・・'#~~':1, '#~~':1)}`といった感じに＃のものまでカウントされてしまいます。この＃を消す方法はあるのでしょうか？

また、カウントの順番を多い順ではなく、1,2,3と番号順にすることはできるのでしょうか？

```
import sys
import os
from collections import Counter

count = []
with open('test.vcf','r') as file:
    lines = file.read().split('\n')

    for line in lines:
        a = line.split('\t')
        CHR = a[0]
        count.append(CHR)

c = Counter(count)
print(c)
```

Comment: [Bcftools](http://samtools.github.io/bcftools/)を使う方法もあります(事前に VCF ファイルを bgzip で圧縮して index を作成しておく必要がありますが)。`bcftools index --stats test.vcf.gz`

Answer (score 1):

[先の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/54971/29826)で記載したとおり[Counter](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)クラスは辞書型のサブクラスであるため、これを利用して実装可能です。

具体的には、[dict.keys()](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys)でキーを一覧し、それから[del](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement)を行うことで可能でしょう。

また、辞書は順序の概念がないためソートは不可能ですが、これもキーを任意の順序にソートしてアクセスすることで対応可能です。

```py
c_keys = c.keys().sort()

for k in c_keys:
    if k[0] == '#':
        del c[k]
    else:
        print(k, c[k])
```

Answer (score 0):

こんな感じで、基本のライブラリと `pandas` を使って実現できるでしょう。

```
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd

# ファイル読み取り＆コメント削除(有効なデータの中に'#'は無いものと仮定)
lines = []
with open('test.vcf','r') as file:
    alltext = file.readlines()
    for line in alltext:
        str = line.strip().split('#')  # 行の前後の空白を削除し、'#'で分割
        if str[0]:                     # コメントでは無い部分だけリスト化
            lines.append(str[0])

# 各行のタブで区切った最初のデータをリスト化
count = []
for line in lines:
    a = line.split('\t')
    count.append(a[0])

# データの出現回数をカウントしてDataFrame化
s = pd.Series(count)
vc = pd.value_counts(s)
df = vc.rename_axis('CHR').to_frame('counts')

# データ文字列の最大長を取得
idx = list(df.index)
n = len(max(idx, key=len))

# 数値データを抽出し、右寄せしてソート
dfnum = df.query('CHR.str.isnumeric()', engine='python')
dfnum = dfnum.rename(index=lambda s: s.rjust(n))
dfnum = dfnum.sort_index()

# 文字列データを抽出し、右寄せしてソート
dfstr = df.query('not CHR.str.isnumeric()', engine='python')
dfstr = dfstr.rename(index=lambda s: s.rjust(n))
dfstr = dfstr.sort_index()

# 数値・文字列のDataFrameを連結
dfall = pd.concat([dfnum, dfstr])

# 結果表示
print(dfall)
```

---

検索したら、.vcf ファイル等を扱うライブラリがあるようですので、そちらを使うのもアリかもしれません。

[cyvcf2](https://pypi.org/project/cyvcf2/)  /  [pysam](https://pypi.org/project/pysam/)  /  [PyVCF](https://pypi.org/project/PyVCF/)
[cyvcf2: fast, flexible variant analysis with Python](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/33/12/1867/2971439)

他に古そうですがこんなまとめページも。
[Python の基礎とバイオインフォマティクス Python 3.4](https://bi.biopapyrus.jp/python/)

---

直接は関係無いですが、専門分野向けパッケージ等も。

[Bioconda](http://bioconda.github.io/)
[biocondaを利用してNGS関連のソフトウェアを一括でインストールする](http://imamachi-n.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/01/14/212719)
[Biocondaを使ってみた](https://bonohu.wordpress.com/2017/07/08/bioconda/)

[Python for Biologists](https://pythonforbiologists.com/)

[Biopython](https://biopython.org/)

Comment: この内容でPandasを使うのは牛刀という感じがします、VCFファイル専用のライブラリを使うのはありですが……

Comment: @PicoSushiさん、確かに import だけで二拍くらいかかっている感じです。けどその後の処理が素直に書ける感じなので良さそうかな、と思いまして。